# Xamarin ios Implement Facebook like scrollview

Tags: c#, ios

I have a simple table view with dynamic content (images). I would like to implement something similar to a Facebook newsfeed and the ability to select an image from the newsfeed/tableview and get a full sized image with the ability to swipe left and right and a close button to exit the view.

So far I have tried to enable dynamic row heights for my images but they still look squashed and aren't scaled properly.

Unfortunately I have searched in vain for this Facebook like implementation for Xamarin.iOS, which is in c#.

Does anyone know how I can get a similar implementation?

Here's my code for dynamic row heights

```
if (TableView != null) {

                TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
                TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 44;

                TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

                // Register the TableView's data source
                TableView.Source = new HomeControllerSource (dataManager.LoadImages(),this);
            }
```

After a row click,I open up the image in another view controller which has a scrollview but it doesn't fill up the whole screen. I would like to implement this part as Facebook does it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching for this, but omitting the xamarin and C# tags as the search criterias? Usually it's a piece of cake to translate smaller sections of Objective C to C#. Now, on topic: I think you want 'UiViewController.PresentViewController'. That way it will take up the entire screen, since it will not be a (direct) child of a navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks @BjarkeSøgaard . I will try the PresentViewController right away. How about the dynamic row heights for the images? I am working with images and would like to have their actual heights in the tableview, without any scaling. The same for the full screen scroll view.

Comment: Dynamic height for rows in iOS seems to always have been a hassle to get working. Even seasoned iOS developers seems to encounter problems with them occasionally, as far as I've heard. I think you need to know, ahead of display, the total height of your row (so any text, image and whatnot), and feed that to the 'GetHeight' method on the tableview delegate.